# With javascript i want to be able to grab the font color which is dynamically changing randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I want to get the font color 
 eg.

```
#FF0000
```

or it could be

```
#568000    etc..
```

**My table**

```
<table class="mytable">
   <th class=vertical bgcolor=#C0C0C0 align=center> <font color=#FF0000 size=2> Test this out</font>
  </th>
  <th class=vertical bgcolor=#C0C0C0 align=center> <font color=#568000 size=2> Test this out</font>
  </th>
</table>
```

Seems like normally with css property I could get with some

```
newInnerDiv.css("background-color");
```

But this is a font tag color INSIDE a TABLE TH element.   How can I get at that font color?  I seems that sibling elements would be for getting the next TH etc...

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/y8ct6b5u/6/

Comment: font tag is deprecated. do not use it.

Comment: `$('.vertical').css('color')` should work

Comment: use what instead?   @BhojendraNepal

Comment: @MillRunner You may use span inside th and define style.

Comment: @Pekka   returns     rgb(0, 0, 0)   ( console.log  )

Comment: because it is black it will return something else if the color is changed @MillRunner how do you dynamically change the color anyway just curious

Comment: So the data is coming down from the database , so they are all user preferences based on business rules etc...

Comment: I do use a transformation script that rotates it to be vertical , and if it is hard coded i can change it no problem , but i want to just capture the value in font tag

Comment: I don't get how to do this     var x = $('.vertical').css('color');
  console.log(x);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/goj7268c/ check this

Answer (score 0):

this works... please have a try in your console.

```
js: document.querySelector('font').color
output:    "#FF0000"
```

Comment: Where could I put that code to grab and apply to each TH font ?    http://jsfiddle.net/y8ct6b5u/5/

Comment: you can use   document.querySelectorAll('font') to get the collection of these font tag elements. and  document.querySelectorAll('font') [index].color to see the value

Answer (score 0):

Try it: its for get color for your table header...

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("font").each(function () {
          var getcolor= $(this).attr("color");
        });
    });
    </script>
```